# Kubernetes no provisionable volume plugin matched

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

Attempting and failing to use NFS storage for Kubernetes volumes.

*persistentvolumeclaim* is unable to bind to already created *persistentvolume*, see below

**Creating persistentvolume**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 192.0.2.100
    path: "/nfsshare"
```

**Creating persistentvolumeclaim**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Event logs for the persistentvolumeclaim shows

```
kubectl get events:
"provisionable volume plugin matched"
```

Any ideas what might be stop k8s to bind the two?

Comment: hi. There is no question which could be answered in your post

Comment: yes poorly written question; how can I identify and solve the event warning "provisionable volume plugin matched"

Comment: First of all describe what you wanted to do, then explain any desired result you'd like to reach

Answer (score 1):

delete any default storage class (nfs) and try creating PV & PVC again

```
 kubectl get sc
 kubectl delete sc
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Running 1.18.5.
Can you elaborate why this would fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is a little late, I just had the same issue.

I have a cluster (in my case OpenShift 4.5), and a default storage class *nfs*.
First, I created a PV, then a PVC, and the PVC got the same error event.

I found out, that on creating a PV I can state the storage class:
`storageClassName: nfs`

Otherwise, for the PV's storageClass a *standard* value was assumed, where the cluster has no provisioner for. That explains the error message.

My full example of the (now bound) PV' spec is:

```
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  nfs:
    server: 10.1.xxx.x
    path: /dir1/dir2
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: nfs
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Answer (score -1):

Add following line in both PV and PVC yaml

spec:
  storageClassName: manual

Comment: can you provide additional context in this answer as to why this solves the question.

Answer (score -1):

It will create PV and use PV claim from that PV